# How to format a input type number field with currency

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to locate examples of how to add commas to a angular `input type="number"` field. Everything I have seen uses a `type="text"`. the issue is I need to keep the wheel that the number field has.

Is it possible to work around this? I have seen some css hacks that only work with chrome.

I need all browsers to work.

Comment: You should use the angular-input-mask: https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks

Comment: I'll go with input=text. Read this: https://www.aeyoun.com/posts/html5-input-number-localization.html

Comment: Currency format example in AngularJS: http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/collections/formattingfilters/

Comment: angularjshub.com/examples/collections/formattingfilters –  mggSof Uses simple text and an input field with type text. The question clearly states that he is looking for input type="number" solution.

Comment: omg its nearly 2017, how is this not a thing yet? building a web app used on mobile (want number keyboard please), where you have to input prices? Trailing zeros to 2 decimals expected? Unlucky, with your super niche requirements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a similar examples for how to add commas to a angular input type="number" field.

try the below example, i have not tried it, but it looks promising

you may use this example to create a directive as per you need 
http://blog.krusen.dk/angularjs-decimals-browsers/

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to your original question, as I don't know whether you can insert commas and currency symbols into number fields. Instead of keeping it as number field, but try this, maybe it will help:

Allow text, and limit user input to only digits.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" numbers-only/>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('numbersOnly', [
    function(){ // limit the input field to numbers only, but retain value as string. Note do not use on type=number input field
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

                modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

                    var transformedInput = inputValue;
                    transformedInput = transformedInput.replace(/\D/g,'');

                    if(transformedInput)
                        transformedInput = parseInt(transformedInput)+"";

                    if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
                        modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        modelCtrl.$render();
                    }

                    return transformedInput;
                });
            }
        };
    }
])
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zLj34V7v7xICyfGnlg3k?p=preview

Comment: the issue that i still face is i dont have the wheel to increase/decrease value with mouse wheel